# Three.js gltf file not loading on web server

Tags: asp.net, nginx, three.js

gltf files wont load in three.js on the web for me. Everything works fine on a local server, but when I upload to web I get 404 errors.

Here's the site: https://surfacecollider.net/Bubble2/

I'm having trouble debugging as everything works fine locally, and my knowledge of backend stuff isn't good enough. It's hosted with fasthosts.co.uk, with asp.net framework, nginx server. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13k82.png)

has it got anything to do with progress event lengthComputable being false, and if so how would I change that?

Comment: A 404 means that the server is not finding the file in the location you've asked for (https://surfacecollider.net/Bubble2/gltf/March_12.gltf). Are you sure that's the right URL? We can't see what's on your server, so just guessing. It's also possible that your server is configured to only allow certain types of files... an NGINX config might help narrow that down.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I think I've resolved the 404 issue by changing the URL. Now I'm getting this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token J in JSON at position 1, and this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0. Here's the new URL of the site: https://surfacecollider.net/lockdown/

Comment: all working now... re-exported the model as a .glb file from Blender and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am working at VS with .glb and .gltf formats.
I added this codes at web.config file and then everything goes on ok
I hope this will solve your problem

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".czml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".czml" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".glsl" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".glsl" mimeType="text/plain" />
      <remove fileExtension=".b3dm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".b3dm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <remove fileExtension=".pnts" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".pnts" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <remove fileExtension=".i3dm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".i3dm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <remove fileExtension=".cmpt" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".cmpt" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <remove fileExtension=".gltf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".gltf" mimeType="model/gltf+json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".bgltf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".bgltf" mimeType="model/gltf-binary" />
      <remove fileExtension=".glb" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".glb" mimeType="model/gltf-binary" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".geojson" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".geojson" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".topojson" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".topojson" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".kml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".kmz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".kmz" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kmz" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".terrain" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".terrain" mimeType="application/vnd.quantized-mesh" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ktx" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ktx" mimeType="image/ktx" />
      <remove fileExtension=".crn" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".crn" mimeType="image/crn" />
    </staticContent>
```

Comment: Problem is mimeMap file extensions